# Trying to convert a kotlin method to java that uses RxJava

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

```
Android Studio 3.1 RC 2
kotlin 1.2.30
```

Signature for the fetchMessage

```
Single<Response> fetchMessage(final String messageId);
```

The kotlin code that I am trying to convert to Java. However, I am not sure where the returns are? As I am new to kotlin and lambda.

```
private fun getMessage(messageId: String): Observable<State> {
        return repository
                .fetchMessage(messageId)
                .flatMap {
                    Single.fromCallable<State>({
                        update(messageId, it, State.COMPLETED)
                        State.COMPLETED
                    })
                }
                .toObservable()
}
```

This is my attempt at trying to convert it. However, the compiler complains of a missing return.

```
public Observable<TranslationChatState> translate(String messageId) {
        return repository
                .fetchMessage(messageId)
                .flatMap(new Func1 <Response, Single<State >>() {
                    @Override
                    public Single<State> call(final Response response) {
                        Single.fromCallable(new Callable<State>() {
                            @Override
                            public State call() {
                                update(messageId, response, State.COMPLETED);
                                return State.COMPLETED;
                            }
                        });
                    } /* complains about no return here */
                })
                .toObservable();
}
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because it is missing the return statement. It should be

```
public Single<State> call(final Response response) {
     return Single.fromCallable(new Callable<State>() {
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Its easy to read the java code. However, Where are the return statements in the kotlin code?

Comment: it still there. Last value of a lambda is the implicit return.